# How can I toggle menu onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JS and coding in general and just don't know how to do what I want it to do; Firstly my code (I still have to clean up my code a bit :P )

```css
 .header {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

.hero-image {
  position: relative;
  background: url("../img/background-image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* MENU */
.header__menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hero-text {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-menu_toggle {
  justify-content: center;

}

.hero-menu_scroll {
 justify-content: center;

}

.header__menu.is-expanded {
 z-index: 99;
}

.beige {
 background-color: #ffd39b;
}

.pink {
 background-color: #d0b2e4;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #FFDE03;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #00B8D4;
} 

.green {
  background-color: #1DE9B6;
}

.black {
 background-color: #414141;
}
```

```html
  <header class="header">
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <button onclick="toggleMenu" class="hero-menu_toggle" id="hero-menu-toggle">Menu</button>
      <h1> Berlin From Below </h1>
      <button class="hero-menu_scroll" id="hero-menu-scroll"> see more </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__menu">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="pink menu-list_item"> <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> </li>
        <li class="yellow menu-list_item"> <a href="people-of-berlin.html">People Of Berlin</a> </li>
        <li class="blue menu-list_item"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
        <li class="green menu-list_item"> <a href="news.html">News</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's what I want to do; 
When the user comes to the site all he sees is a background-image and two buttons (Menu & See More).

- If the user clicks on the menu button I want my menu to pop up and cover the entire screen, ideally with a transition effect where the colors gradually fill the screen

I hope it's understandable what I want it to do.

Comment: First off, you have not given us your JS. Please add it to the question. Second, it is not clear what you have tried to do to make it work.

Comment: Try this example https://www.cssscript.com/css-fullscreen-sliding-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples of different menu styles on the W3Schools site [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp).

See the attached snippet from W3Schools:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference." - *StackOverflow scripture*. 
   Also, any answer as general as `use X` is very unlikely to be helpful in any case, and especially when the OP is a novice with the language.